# 405 method not allowed in spring mvc but other actions and controller working fine?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jax-rs

I am new to Spring and my other controller running good but when I am trying to call `getmyfriends` endpoint, I got the `405 Method Not Allowed`:

```
@Controller
@Path("friends")
public class FreindsJersey {

    @Autowired
    private FriendsService friendsService;

    @POST
    @Path("getmyfriends")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getAllMyFriends(String json) {
        ReturnData returnData = (ReturnData) Parser.getJsonFromString(json, ReturnData.class);
        return Response.ok(friendsService.getMyFriendsList(returnData).getContainer()).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("unfriend/{userId}/{friendId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response unfriendUser(@PathParam("userId") long userId, @PathParam("friendId") long friendId) {
        return Response.ok(friendsService.deleteAFriendOfTheUser(userId, friendId).getContainer()).build();
    }

}
```

The URL I'm calling is http://localhost:8080/Indulgge/friends/getmyfriends

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR: `getAllMyFriends` requires `POST`

When you enter a URL into your browser, it will use `GET`. You cannot `POST` from the URL bar.

Your code only allows `POST`.

```
@POST // <-- here
@Path("getmyfriends")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getAllMyFriends(String json) {
    ReturnData returnData = (ReturnData) Parser.getJsonFromString(json, ReturnData.class);
    return Response.ok(friendsService.getMyFriendsList(returnData).getContainer()).build();
}
```

---

In fact, you have it backwards - [**safe** and **idempotent**](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/) requests should be `GET` (such as `getAllMyFriends`); **unsafe** and **non-idempotent** requests should be `POST` (such as `unfriendUser`).